# React Form controlled by a Flux Store (Best practice?)

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, reactjs-flux

So I have a big component that would be my form:

```
<form>
 <FirstComponent value={this.state.firstValue}/>
 <SecondComponent value={this.state.secondValue}/>
 {more components here}
 <input type="submit" ... />
</form>
```

This form component is listening for a store that updates its values using `firstAction`, `secondAction`, etc.

Note: Component updates its state based on store.getState() that returns `{firstValue: something, secondValue: something, etc}`

So let's say my `FirstComponent`is an input:

```
<input type="text" value={this.props.value} 
   onChange={(e)=>this.props.firstAction(e.target.value)}
</input>
```

Ok, so the `onChange` fires the prop `firstAction` which is actually the Flux action that will update my store and make the form to re-render. I have two good things here, when user submits the form, I can check the value of FirstComponent in my store and I also control all my state from the parent component.

However, this `onChange` callback will call an action every time the user types one character (so it can produce a lot of calls therefore re-renders) <-- can this provoke serious performance issues?

Instead, I could use refs and when the user press the submit button, get `this.refs.myFirstComponent.state`... and I will have the value too (that would be [Uncontrolled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components)?) But this does not sound like a recommendation from the community.

So my question is, is the first approach I described above a good way to go? How can I optimize it? So a re-render that should only affect FirstComponent does not make SecondComponent and so on to re-render? Is `shouldComponentUpdate`the only way to go here?

---

**Edit 1:**

With the first approach I am facing a problem... I have an e2e test using WebdriverIO adding a value into the text field: http://webdriver.io/api/action/setValue.html

I don't know why but if I am trying to add the word "Testing" into the input, webdriver will only add the last letter. This problem is gone if not using state/store at all. However, if I have the state internally to my `FirstComponent`, something like:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} 
   onChange={(e)=>this.setState({firstValue: e.target.value})}
   onBlur={()=>this.props.callback(this.state.firstValue)}
</input>
```

In this case, component seems to react faster while typing (only renders itself), and then, when user removes focus it updates the store. I have to say, I don't like this approach because it doesn't follow the pattern of take your state up (and I feel I am duplicating the state) BUT it seems to work faster and more important: My e2e test works. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your first approach (i.e. `onChange` fires flux action which updates the store and make your form re-render) seems like a good way to go. I've been using it like that and I've seen other people using it like that, too.

Regarding your following comment:

> However, this onChange callback will call an action every time the user types one character (so it can produce a lot of calls therefore re-renders) <-- can this provoke serious performance issues?

Yes, I believe so. I once created a component that contains many other components along with some input fields. Whenever I typed a character in an input field, the whole component (with other components it includes and the input fields) got re-rendered, causing the performance problem. It was noticeable if I typed fast. You can actually verify it using https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html.

Anyway, how I got around the problem is, as you mentioned, by implementing `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

A small tip I'd like to mention is creating a custom `<Input />` component that wraps around `<input />` and implementing `shouldComponentUpdate()`  (i.e. `this.props.value !== nextProps.value || this.props.checked !== nextProps.checked`) That way, if you create a form component, for example, with many input fields (using the custom `<Input />`), only the input field that is changed gets re-rendered.

I'd love to see how other people approach this problem, too, though.

Comment: Check my Edit 1, using the action approach I faced a problem with my e2e tests...

Comment: Why would it cause performance issues? I thought that React's virtual DOM handles such checks internally and only renders, what has changed.  It's the notable feature of React, when it comes to performance. Am I wrong?